# Permission not working in yii2 admin

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user

I have installed `yii2-user`, `yii2-admin` extensions and given permission to user 'harlan' to /country/* 
i.e do anything in country controller.

When I find the value of

```
Yii::$app->user->can('/country/index')
```

in my code, it shows "1" which means I have set the permission correctly.

For some reason the permission is not working. It gives me the error when I try to go to web/country/index

```
Forbidden (#403)
You are not allowed to perform this action.
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: show the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `permissionName` in `Yii::$app->user->can($permissionName)`.